# iOS code keeps giving 'Invalid Token' error

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I am using Pushsharp v4.0.10 and coding in C# on VS2013.

I am trying to create a C# console application, that will run server side, and am using the ANPS sample code on the Pushsharp github page but when I run it, it fails and I get the 'Invalid token' error. I have checked and even recreated the sandbox certificates and provisioning profiles needed to create the device token that i use in the code but no matter what i do it still gives the error. The token is created in a separate mobile app.

Any advice or a way to check to see if the certificates are correct from anybody who has had this error before would be very helpful.

Comment: Did you find out why this was happening?

Comment: @PaulDiston Unfortunately we havent solved this issue yet. We do think it is caused by us not using the correct production/sandbox certificates, but we just cant get it to work with either. Ill post here if we do ever figure it out.

Comment: Not sure my solution here would help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42810721/pushsharp-returns-invalid-token-for-newly-created-p12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it looks like i was just not creating and certificates for iOS properly. I found this website that has a good explanation and their method worked.

This is for creating the certificates on Windows: [Link](http://www.grenadeco.com/tutorial/how-to-generate-apn-certificates-on-windows-using-openssl/)